# Convert number within span to date format | Javascript |

Tags: javascript, date, date-formatting

I have a number (20150918) within the span of a html document. I can only control the html document with CSS and javascript. I want to change the number 20150918 to be in a more readable date format (e.g: 2015/09/18).

It's become obvious to me that I can't use CSS to change attributes so my assumption is that I can only use javascript for this. This feels like a simple question but I couldn't find anything out there where the numbers I am formatting are already within the HTML.

So basically the span I am trying to update looks like this right now:

```
<span id="changeme">20150918</span>
```

Any help would be appreciated, if I've missed something blindingly obvious I apologise..

Comment: these are in miliseconds or real date ?

Comment: will the string always be in YYYYMMDD format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working code in JavaScript:

```
var formatForDate = function(element) {
  var originalText = element.innerText;

  var year = originalText.substring(0,3);
  var month = originalText.substring(4,5);
  var day = originalText.substring(6,7);

  element.innerText = [year, month, day].join('/');
}
```

To use it, simply give him the HTML element like this:

```
formatForDate(document.querySelector('#changeme'));
```

Comment: Thankyou, I'll give this a go later on today and let you know how I get along :)

Comment: Thanks,that worked! The numbers needed to be slightly different though:

    var year = originalText.substring(0,4);
    var month = originalText.substring(4,6);
    var day = originalText.substring(6,9);

Comment: Mark it as the answer for other persons

Answer (score 1):

Capture the element:

```
var span = document.getElementById("changeme");
```

Capture the string:

```
var old_format = span.innerHTML;
```

Create a pattern that identify data positions:

```
var pattern = /(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/;
```

Replace the string with the new pattern:

```
var new_format = old_format.replace( pattern,'$1/$2/$3' );
```

Output result:

```
span.innerHTML = new_format;
```

Here is the snippet:

```js
var span = document.getElementById("changeme");

var old_format = span.innerHTML;

var pattern = /(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/;
    
var new_format = old_format.replace( pattern,'$1/$2/$3' );

span.innerHTML = new_format;
```

```html
<span id="changeme">20150919</span>
```

Comment: Your code requires jQuery to work. Since the question doesn't reference it, you should avoid it.

Comment: @David I think there is no jquery tag with question ??

Comment: Yeah, I'm not allowed any external libraries so can't use Jquery but I cheekily found a way to get to the javascript library on the page...